# Trying to build a project on os 10.13 which used to build fine on 10.9

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My project uses Cocoapods with OCMock.  When I am building, my test target is failing with a whole bunch of "unable to open dependencies file" errors, and a bunch of warnings about unused argument `-MT` and `-MF` ... When I search the build settings for this target, I see nothing with an `-MT` or `-MF` flag anywhere....  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might be wrong?

```
Showing Recent Messages
WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Script-AF36FA868309454FBF7107CF.sh (in target 'BlueWizardTests' from project 'BlueWizard')
    cd /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard
    write-file /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Script-AF36FA868309454FBF7107CF.sh

ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Products/Debug/BlueWizard.app/Contents/PlugIns/BlueWizardTests.xctest/Contents/Info.plist /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/BlueWizardTests/Info.plist (in target 'BlueWizardTests' from project 'BlueWizard')
    cd /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/BlueWizardTests/Info.plist -producttype com.apple.product-type.bundle.unit-test -expandbuildsettings -platform macosx -o /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Products/Debug/BlueWizard.app/Contents/PlugIns/BlueWizardTests.xctest/Contents/Info.plist

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Script-AF36FA868309454FBF7107CF.sh (in target 'BlueWizardTests' from project 'BlueWizard')
    cd /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard
    /bin/sh -c /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Script-AF36FA868309454FBF7107CF.sh

WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/BlueWizardTests.LinkFileList (in target 'BlueWizardTests' from project 'BlueWizard')
    cd /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard
    write-file /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/BlueWizardTests.LinkFileList

CompileC /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ReflectorTests.o /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/BlueWizardTests/ReflectorTests.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'BlueWizardTests' from project 'BlueWizard')
    cd /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target arm64-apple-macos10.10 -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wquoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -index-store-path /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/BlueWizardTests-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/BlueWizardTests-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/BlueWizardTests-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/BlueWizardTests-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/Pods/Headers/Public/OCMock -I/Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/usr/include -I/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -I/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Products/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -isystem /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/Pods/Headers/Public/OCMock -isystem /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ReflectorTests.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ReflectorTests.dia -c /Users/patrick/coding/objective_c/BlueWizard/BlueWizardTests/ReflectorTests.m -o /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ReflectorTests.o -index-unit-output-path /BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ReflectorTests.o

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MT dependencies' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-MF /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ReflectorTests.d' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
error: unable to open dependencies file (/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueWizard-euxbokhjjtsgvcfsesnkxzvwacqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/BlueWizard.build/Debug/BlueWizardTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ReflectorTests.d) (in target 'BlueWizardTests' from project 'BlueWizard')
Command CompileC emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

... and a billion other identical errors
```